# Is it possible to use directive in uib-popover-template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-popover

I know there's a way to use .html like `uib-popover-template="myTemplate.html"`, but what about directive like `uib-popover-template="<my-template-style>...</my-template-style>"`? Didn't find it in the document so i guess no? Quite new to angularjs and ui-grid, not sure if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Regarding official documentation, `uib-popover-html` could fit with your need, but the HTML won't be compiled. So it appears that the only way to achieve your need is to use an external file that contains your directive.

Comment: Hi @Zooly, by external file do you mean an external html file? I thought using a tag is the only way to use directive. Can you give me an example about "use an external file that contains your directive"?

Comment: I mean `uib-popover-template="your-file.html"`